# How do I find $9^{17} \bmod 7$ without a calculator

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I've seen some examples of similar problems but I don't understand how they were solved. How would I solve
$$
9^{17} \bmod 7
$$
without calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work out patterns to get there. In this case, $9 \equiv 2 \mod 7$, so $9^3 \equiv 2^3 = 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$. Then we reduce $17 \mod 3$ and get $2$. So $9^{17} \equiv 9^{3 \cdot 5+2} = 1^5\cdot 9^2\equiv 2^2 = 4 \mod 7$